# Access SQL 0/1 variable, 3 criteria: 1. Values in column A identical, 2. Value in column B is NOT the largest, and 3. Value in column C IS the largest

Tags: jquery, sql, ms-access, iif

As stated in the title, I need to run some SQL in Access, which gives me a 0/1 variable based on three criterie. Firstly, the new variable must compare across all values in column A, that are the same. Secondly, it has to check, if the value in comlumn B is the largest (in my case, it mustn't be), and thirdly, is has to check if the value of column C is the largest (in my case, it must be).

Normally I would run a simple IIf statement across the columns of one row, but here, I need it to compare across all values in column A, that are the same, and see, if there is a "not largest" value in comlum B with a corresponding "largest value" in column C.

I'we read in a lot of discussions, that you need to create a new query for this purpose, but would it be possible to do it within a query and get a new variable in column D, giving the 0/1 variable?

To make it perfectly clear, my data looks something like the following:

```
A     B      C
10    4   12-04-2014
10    5   02-17-2015
10    7   08-11-2016
10    8   08-31-2016
10    6   09-05-2016
```

And there would be houndreds of thousinds of rows, and where A would be different from 10.

So in this case, only the last row would get the value 1 in column D, as it has the latest date, but is not the highest value in column B for the ID value in column A.

Any help is much appreciated!

- Mark

Comment: In a plain term, you want to be able to select the highest value in column C and assign a value 1 to the corresponding row in column D. Right?

Comment: Not exactly. That is only the first criteria. The value 1 in D can only be obtained, if the value in C is the highest, the value in B is NOT the highest. And it needs to take into account, that it can only compare the values in B and C where the value in A is identiacal across rows.

Comment: The thing is, the I need to measure return to a given phase, which is why column B is important, and the value cannot be the highest in this column.

Comment: Then Column A Identical across rows? you mean , the same all through ?

Comment: However, your point could be used, given a possible 3-step-approach.
If you could assign the value 1 in column D given the highest value in column C for the ID-value in column A, and then do the same thing for column B - i.e. giving the value 1 in column E if the value in column B is the highest, given the ID-value in column A.

Then you would be able to have a third 0/1 variable in column F, hvis gives the value 1 if column E is 0 and column D is 1.

Could this be done?

Comment: Column A is NOT identical for all rows in the dataset. I need to only compare columns B and C for the rows where the value in column A is the same however.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT x.a,x.b,x.c,
  CASE
    WHEN x.b<>(SELECT max(xx.b) FROM yourtable xx WHERE xx.a=x.a)
     AND x.c=(SELECT max(xx.c) FROM yourtable xx WHERE xx.a=x.a)
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END AS d
FROM yourtable x
```

Using OVER (PARTITION BY x.a) would be more efficient, but Access doesn't allow this, AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, you can do this as:

```
select t.*,
       iif(x.b <> (select max(tt.b) from t as tt where tt.a = t.a) and
           x.b = (select max(tt.c) from t as tt where tt.a = t.a), 1, 0
          ) as flag
from t;
```

You can also handle this using aggregation:

```
select t.*,
       iif(tt.maxb <> t.b and tt.maxc = t.c, 1, 0) as flag
from t inner join
     (select tt.a, max(tt.b) as maxb, max(t.c) as maxc
      from t as tt
      group by tt.a
     ) as tt
     on tt.a = t.a;
```